# Delphi items compare between 2 listboxes

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I want to know how to compare items between listboxes. On my main form there are two listboxes. I want to add item from 1st to 2nd with a click event but when use it, the same item will multiply on 2nd listbox. Any idea to solve *"the file already exists"* ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    if ListBox1.Selected[i] then                       
      ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
end;
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what you're asking, but if you want to add the item that you select in the 1st list box to the 2nd list box, only when that item is not already there, try to use `...if ListBox1.Selected[i] then if ListBox2.Items.IndexOf(ListBox1.Items[i]) = -1 then ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);`.

Comment: I've made a short video about this question http://youtu.be/m7uxqFQDSSI in which we create a simple Delphi application to demonstrate the problem and how the accepted answer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you got a single-select listbox1:

```
if Listbox2.Items.IndexOf(Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex]) = -1 then
begin
  // Doesn't exist yet. Safe to add
end;
```

For multi-select (which your code seems to imply):

```
for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  if (ListBox1.Selected[i] and (ListBox2.Items.IndexOf(ListBox1.Items[i]) = -1) then                       
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
```

The latter will work for single-select too, I think.

Comment: Here is a youtube video answering this very question.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7uxqFQDSSI&feature=g-u-u   Thanks Alister!